# Can I use an insecure endpoint for Kubernetes API in Docker for Mac?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-mac

When I run Kubernetes in Docker for Mac, the Kube API only seems to be accessible from a secure endpoint of https://localhost:6443/

With minikube I was able to use an insecure endpoint for Kube API like http://localhost:8080/

Is there any way to use an insecure endpoint for Kube API in Kubernetes in Docker for Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be running an old version of Kubernetes with minikube.

The default insecure port for the kube-apiserver is 8080, but that's disabled on the latest Kubernetes versions in the kube-apiserver with the flag: `--insecure-port=0`.

You can always delete that line from your `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` file.

You also need to add this option `--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0` as per [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49933).

Then restart the kube-apiserver.

Tip: Docker/Kubernetes runs on [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) VM(s) on your Mac. So to modify the Kubernetes configs you'll have to connect to your [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) VM(s). You can do it with something like this: `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty` or `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

Adding more details: So the port 6443 is forwarded to the host using [vpnkit](https://github.com/moby/vpnkit). To make port 8080 available on the host you have to also expose that port with vpnkit. If you screen into the hyperkit vm you'll see that port mappings are defined in `/var/vpnkit/port`. There's a `README` file on that directory that you can follow to expose port 8080.

Comment: I can't find the `kube-apiserver.yaml` file on my Mac. Any idea how to change that setting in the docker for mac Kubernetes?

Comment: Looks like Kubernetes in Docker for Mac is [Not Configurable](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/kubernetes/#example-app) "_The Kubernetes server runs locally within your Docker instance, is not configurable, and is a single-node cluster._" Why even have it then...?

Comment: There might be a way. Added at the bottom of the answer

Comment: I have never used `screen` before and I'm struggling with it. Is the goal to screen into a terminal session and then find the `kube-apiserver.yaml` and modify it? Will I need to do this every time I boot up docker for mac?

Comment: That's the goal. You don't have to do every time you boot up docker for mac. It gets saved on the VM storage.

Comment: I used `screen` on that file twice because I didn't know what I was doing and now everything is garbled when I use `screen -r <session>`. Not sure how to clear them or reset them. i have 4 of those sessions now when I use `screen -list`.

Comment: You can kill the screen processes: `kill -9 <pid>` and start from the beginning

Comment: Had to restart docker. Then I was able to use `screen` and find the `kube-apiserver.yaml` file and modify it. Changed `--inescure-port` to 8080. Restarted docker, but still can't access Kube API on http://localhost:8080/api/v1/

Comment: I'm getting *Connection refused*

Comment: Here is the config file: https://pastebin.com/raw/GpbW2ftM I checked that 8080 is still configured when docker restarts.

Comment: Try also adding this `--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0`. Did your kube-apiserver start at all? run a `docker ps` inside the VM to check.

Comment: Added `--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0`, restarted and still got a *Connection refused*. From `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` the docker command doesn't exist. `linuxkit-025000000001:~# docker ps
-sh: docker: not found`

Comment: your kube-apiserver might not be running anymore. Try `ps -Af` .. see the processes running on the VM.

Comment: But still: `$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

Comment: can you a curl within the VM?  maybe it's not available. It could be a firewall rule somewhere.

Comment: Run this to check if something is listening on port 8080 `netstat -tunaple  | grep 8080`

Comment: `linuxkit-025000000001:~# netstat -tunaple | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3214/kube-apiserver`

Comment: And here is what I see that is listening on my mac: `$ lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | grep LISTEN` `com.docke 63596 bfrede200   22u  IPv4 0xa7cb42b3c642ffc9      0t0  TCP *:6443 (LISTEN)`
`com.docke 63596 bfrede200   23u  IPv6 0xa7cb42b3b29e6cc1      0t0  TCP [::1]:6443 (LISTEN)`

Comment: it's vpnkit. It's not forwarding port 8080 to the vm.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that port forwarding issue.

Comment: don't know either. I'll see if I can dig something up. What's the problem with minikube?

Comment: Nothing. I'm switching back to `minikube` because Docker for Mac's Kubernetes is clearly not useful for me. I thought it would be easier to use. I thought wrong :D

Comment: Thank you @Rico so much for this answer. Been struggling with this stuff for 2 days.